# OnClick con java Script no funciona en Mac

Tags: javascript, macos

Tengo unas funciones que trabajan cuando  mando a llamar el evento de javascript `onClick`. Ya esta en producción la aplicación web, en Windows funciona correctamente en cualquier navegador, pero en MacOS, algunas veces no funciona sino hasta el 3er click y solo así entra a la función.

¿Alguien sabe cómo podría solucionar esto? Les dejo mi código.

```
document.getElementById('F5mon').onclick = function() {
    let mon = document.getElementById('F5mon');
    if(mon.value == "Seleccione moneda") {
      mon.style.borderColor= "red";
    } else{
      mon.style.borderColor= "black";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante 
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). 
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas! Recuerda también añadir detalles relevantes como el contenido de la consola en el navegador sobre Mac OSx que estés usando, nombre y versión del navegador, etc. No sabemos si encontraste un bug! :)

Comment: Muestranos tu código. Aclara además, si no funcinoa en ningún navegador, en ningún dispositivo _Mac_, incluyendo PC's, tabletas y teléfonos. O el problema se da con algún navegador específico, o en algún dispositivo específico?

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822